# Table reload data is not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my app five tab bars are using.in the 5th tab one table view is there.here im retrieving and array and displaying in table view.The contents of array are displaying correctly in NSLog.But only the first content in the array is displaying in cell.Can anyone help me how to solve this issue please..
Below is the code i used and can anyone give me a hand where im going wrong please..

Here is where im adding the contents

```
-(IBAction)Done
{
NSString *message = [df stringFromDate:itemDate];
    NSLog(@"message1234 %@",message);
dates= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            NSUserDefaults *currentDefaults7 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            NSData *dataRepresentingSavedArray7 = [currentDefaults7 objectForKey:@"datingg"];
            NSMutableArray *oldSavedArray7 = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataRepresentingSavedArray7];
    if(dates!=nil)
        {

            dates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:oldSavedArray7];

        }
        [dates addObject:message];
        NSUserDefaults *currentDefaults3 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [currentDefaults3 setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dates] forKey:@"datingg"];
        [currentDefaults3 synchronize];
        NSLog(@"%@dates ate getting heree",dates);
```

Here is where im retreiving the contents(fifth tab)

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated

    {
        NSLog(@"ddddd");
        NSUserDefaults *currentDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSData *dataRepresentingSavedArray = [currentDefaults objectForKey:@"datingg"];
        NSMutableArray *oldSavedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataRepresentingSavedArray];
        datedisplay = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:oldSavedArray];
        NSLog(@"%@",datedisplay);

        [self.tab reloadData];
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    }

    - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {




        [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    }

    - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    }

    - (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    }

    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
        // Return YES for supported orientations
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    }

    #pragma mark - Table view data source

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
    //#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
    //#warning Incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return 1;
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }
        if(i<[datedisplay count])
        {
        // Configure the cell...
          cell.textLabel.text=[datedisplay objectAtIndex:i];
        i++;
        }
        [self.tab reloadData];                       
        return cell;
    }

    /*
    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return YES;
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support editing the table view.
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
            // Delete the row from the data source
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        }   
        else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }   
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support rearranging the table view.
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
    {
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
    - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
        return YES;
    }
    */

    #pragma mark - Table view delegate

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
        /*
         <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
         // ...
         // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
         [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
         [detailViewController release];
         */
    }

   @end
    In NSLog it is showing
    Reminder[6448:207] (
        "02 04-12",
        "02 03-12",
        "03 04-20"
    )
![enter image description here][1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are telling your table it only has one row.

```
(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
     return [datedisplay count];
 }
```

Instead of what you have.

Comment: thanks a lot i will accept it after 4 minutes.Please tell me why it is not showing contents without relaunch app

Comment: Quitting and relaunching, or going back to the home screen and re-entering the app?

Comment: @ jrturton,ie pressing the home button and again taking the app.also when again running in simulator it is showing

Comment: Are you calling tableView:didAddRowView:forRow: when you are adding a row ?

Comment: What is self.tab in your viewdidload method? Shouldn't that be self.tableView if we are looking at a UITableViewController?

Comment: Don't remove it, replace it with [self.tableView reloadData];

Comment: jrturton .Thanku.now it is showing two datas correctly,but when adding more it is not showing.but when pressing home button and take again it shows all.I place ur code in viewwill appear.what im doing wrong nw.plz help me

Comment: When you add new data, you have to let the tableView know, either by the method in Harald's comment or by calling reloaddata again. You should post a new question, showing where you are adding data as this shouldn't be done in comments.

Comment: jrturton i edited my question.plz refer and tell me where im going wrong.Also can you give me the correct format of  Harald Scheirich answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3096/discussion-between-jrturton-and-senorina)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of this

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
//#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 1;
}
```

use

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
//#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [datedisplay count];
}
```

Comment: @senorina can to tell me your problem a little bit more clearly

Comment: when saving the array content,it is retriving in another tab and when move to that tab it is showing nothing.but when i press home button and again takes the app it is displaying correctly in table view.why it is so?